# Failed to rename compiled query -Redshift

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bigdata, amazon-redshift

While running multiple insert query on redshift I am facing the following issue:

```
context:   'result == 0' - failed to rename compiled query /rds/bin/padb.1.0.871/data/exec/156/1.473317247000000
```

Some data is inserted properly but it fails after inserting few records.I have google the issue but found no solution.
Thanks.

Comment: See the problem has been reported several times at AWS Develop forum, you'd better to check the problem with aws directly. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=567368, https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=589240

Comment: Yes I have checked that link already but that question is not yet answered